# Cscript. How to make a multi-colored text

Tags: vbscript, console, jscript, wsh

I'm trying to get a multi-colored text to the console using Cscript.

```
WScript.Echo('\033[31m' + 'Some Text' + '\033[0m');
```

This solution does not work. Is there any way to get the multi-colored text to the console?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the text color/foreground is not supported.

You can change the background color.

```
  te.SetRGBEntry(9, 16711680);
```

will change it to a light blue.